# □ -> X Conversion

Tags: circuit-analysis, conversion, y-to-delta

In cicuit analasys to make a circuit easier you can use delta wye conversion. This means that when there part of a circuit with 3 nodes, where each of the 3 resistors ar in betwen 2 nodes, this can be easily converted to a part of circuit with 4 nodes where one is a pivot node and between itself and another node there is a restor in between.

I was wondering if there a way to convert 4, where there are 4 resitors placed inbetween 2 nodes to turn into a part of circuit with 5 nodes where one is added and each of the 4 resistor is connexted to this node and another.

Like i have seen the method on how the formulas of delt to wye and vice versa work. But will superposition work in this case?

[image: Square to X Conversion]

And Rmn=?, Rno=?, Rop=?, Rpm=?

I hope there is a way to solve this problem.

Comment: The general form of the Y-Δ transform is called the star-polygon transform.